# Jest async test with event emitter isn't ending

Tags: node.js, testing, jestjs

I'm testing a Nodejs process which read from a redis queue, do some stuff, push the output into another redis queue.

In order to blackbox test this process i'm using various mocks for dbs and caches, but leaving all the logic untouched. In particular the mock for redis does emit an event when lpush-ing into the output queue. My hope is to catch that event inside the test() and perform my checks.

The issue is that the full thing "works", the event is fired, catched inside the test() and values are there and they are also correct, BUT i can't manage to let the test end. In the various tries i even got jest to never close, even with the default 5s timeout.

Any hint? A workaround is to mock the function that push in the output queue inside my logic, but i don't like it.

```
describe('foo', () => {
  describe('bar', () => {
    const fakeData = [{ id: 1 }]
    const EE = new EventEmitter()
    beforeAll(() => {
      redisMock.new = jest.fn(() => ({
        brpop: jest.fn(() => fakeData.pop()),
        lpush: jest.fn((destQueue, data) => EE.emit('lpush', { destQueue, data })),
      }))
      mylogicWhichUsesRedis.start()
    })
    test('my test', (done) => {
      EE.once('lpush', (params) => {
        console.log(params)
        expect(params.destQueue).toEqual('something')
        console.log('test') // it will get till here
        done()
      })
    })
  })
})
```

PS adding also another test version which still doesn't work. The idea of this version is to try to avoid context issue for the done().

```
test('foobar', async () => {
  const params = await new Promise((resolve) => {
    EE.once('lpush', resolve)
  })
  expect(params.destQueue).toEqual('something')
  console.log('this get printed')
})
```

Comment: You're probably missing the event because you're calling your function under test before `EE.once`.    Move `mylogicWhichUsesRedis.start()` to after `EE.once`

Comment: I'm not missing the event, the console.logs are executed, is the done() which isn't getting catched by jest, the test doesn't end.

Comment: You should post your imports and package versions then.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to understand the issue: the test itself and the design are good, nothing wrong with them, the issue is that the

> mylogicWhichUsesRedis.start()

had a case where it's recalling itself (not recursively) and this for some reason makes Jest go crazy. The function keeps recalling till infinity and the Jest test timeout isn't triggered for some reason.

I added a flag/semaphore to manage this behaviour from outside and worked as a charm.

```
test('my test', (done) => {
  EE.once('lpush', (params) => {
    mylogicWhichUsesRedis.mustStop = true // this block the eternal execution
    expect(params.destQueue).toEqual('something')
    done()
  })
})
```